# angularjs $watch old value and new value are the same

Tags: angularjs

My intention is to watch a model within scope, and find difference between old value and new value.

However, I found old value and new value are all the same from the following code.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.markers = {};
  $scope.$watchCollection('markers', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
  });
  $timeout( function() {
    $scope.markers.foo = 1;
  }, 500);
  $timeout( function() {
    $scope.markers.bar = 2;
  }, 500);
});
```

output:

```
being watched oldValue: Object {} newValue: Object {} script.js:6
being watched oldValue: Object {foo: 1} newValue: Object {foo: 1} script.js:6
being watched oldValue: Object {foo: 1, bar: 2} newValue: Object {foo: 1, bar: 2}
```

Why are they the same, and if it's intentional, then why?

here is code, http://plnkr.co/edit/rfMCF4x6CmVVT957DPSS?p=preview

Comment: Either the documentation is not up-to-date or it is a bug. `newValue === oldValue` states `false` so I would tend to think that it is a bug.

Comment: Turns out it's a known bug:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621

Comment: I assumed $watchCollection is shortcut of deep $watch. It seems not.

Comment: Great, ten minutes of my life wasted. Thanks for this question, saved me lots of time. :)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use `$watch` instead, that seems to work.  If you want to watch all the properties on the object as well (as you are doing), you need to add `true` as the third parameter to the watch.  This sets up a deep watch.

[Here is a working plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Wr14BY?p=preview)

JS:

```
app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
  $scope.markers = {};
  $scope.$watch('markers', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log('being watched oldValue:', oldValue, 'newValue:', newValue);
  }, true);
  $timeout( function() {
    $scope.markers.foo = 1;
  }, 500);
  $timeout( function() {
    $scope.markers.bar = 2;
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: The documentation for watchCollection says: "Shallow watches the properties of an object and fires whenever any of the properties change (for arrays, this implies watching the array items; for object maps, this implies watching the properties).". So using watchCollection on an object is correct.

Comment: @JBNizet Strange then,  I did try to do a deep watch (adding true) for the watchCollection first, but it didn't work.  Regular deep watch did though.  :)  I've edited the answer so I'm not making assumptions between the two.

Comment: JB, watchCollection is broken. Yes, it fires when the properties change, no, it doesn't save the old values to return them, as specified in the documentation. Instead, you get a copy of the new data in a new and separate object.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621

Answer (score 13):

I found that it's very useful to check if the new and old value are equal (in values) and skip the process if that's the case to avoid unexpected behavior. You can use [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals) to achieve that. Here's an example:

JS:

```
$scope.$watch('myObject', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)){
        return; // simply skip that
    }
});
```

Comment: Beware! This is a really bad practice that can easily cause issues in certain cases. For example, when the watched property is first set (i.e. transitions from undefined to some value) the watch listener is called with the newValue and oldValue bot set to the new value and if this check is present the change will be ignored. You can read more about this here:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11565

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621

and it seems not being fixed.

Comment: It is fixed now: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621#issuecomment-37981379

Answer (score 2):

The values are passed as parameters

```
$scope.$watch('foo', function (newValue, oldValue) {
  // ...
}
```