# Angular JS filter - Do not update DOM value if new value is empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on a data heavy Angular project in which I have a ng-repeat where many values get updated every second. If a value is empty, it now updates the DOM to show an empty value; which is correct behaviour.

**Needed solution**

What I want is a filter or expression which doesn't update the value in the DOM when the new value is empty or NULL. Latching data, I believe they call it.

**Possible solutions**

I found a couple of possible solutions with $watch, but I believe they are not suitable in ng-repeat, or at least not efficient:
[angularjs $watch old value and new value are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751954/angularjs-watch-old-value-and-new-value-are-the-same)

**Example of what I would like to achieve: (this does not work)**

```
app.filter('latchIt', function () {
  return function (valueOld, valueNew) {
    if (valueNew == '') {
      // Do not update the DOM for this value, perhaps a return of the old value
      return valueOld;
    } else {
      return valueNew;
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="item" ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
  <div class="value" ng-repeat="value in item.data">{{ value | latchIt }}</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help & advice you can give me.

Comment: Although it might be possible, I don't think filters are well suited for this task. Instead look to ng-model or create your own directive which can keep track of both values (old and current).

Comment: How are the values get updated? Do you send an ajax call to the server?

Comment: The value of `item.data` should be getting processed to compare old and new values before it ever hits the repeat structure. Create a controller or update your ajax call to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure filters will change the behavior of whether it will be updated or not

Comment: I begin to understand that a directive is the way to go. I thought a directive and a ng-repeat would conflict each other, but that was probably a wrong assumption on my part.

The values are updated through a websocket, so I've got asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a directive for that:

codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVXgjz

```
angular.module('app').directive('latched', [function() {
  return {
    template: '<span>{{saved}}</span>',
    link: function($scope) {
      $scope.$watch('value', function(val) {
        if (!$scope.saved) {
          $scope.saved = val || 'Not defined yet';
        }
        if (val) {
          $scope.saved = val;
        } 
      })
    },
    scope: {
      value: '='
    }
  }
}])
```

Comment: Thanks for your example, maybe it's not bad at all to use the $watch function then, I will try this out.

Comment: I have been developing angular for 2 years now, and I think that the watch function has gotten a bad name for no real reason. Just need to avoid using the deep watch and on complex objects, and it's fine to watch thousands if not more of values.

Comment: Great to hear, I've got it working based on your example! Thanks a lot :)
Small follow up question, what is the scope: { value: '='} part for at the end? It seems my directive works with and without it.

Comment: On second thought, my follow-up question is something that I can find out myself as it's documented in Angular. Thanks again! https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Np, and you can without it, and you can use the new bindToController that came in angular 1.4, it's for isolation so your directive doesn't mess up any other scope that depends on value.

Answer (score 0):

Well I would say that $watch option is good enough to use it, but if you are agains it you can try to combine old collection values and new collection values according to your business rules in controller/directive and after than pass it to view.