# Why would you compare an old value and a new value with angular watch to see if they are equal

Tags: angularjs

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25294989/3708225) in which the author is doing

```
$scope.$watch('myObject', function(newValue, oldValue){
    if(angular.equals(newValue, oldValue)){
         return; 
     }
});
```

Why would newValue and oldValue ever be the same here?  My understanding of `$watch` is that it only fires when `myObject` changes.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely useless in the case of `$watch` usage. The answer you pointed does not add anything. Nevertheless, the original question is meaningful and it is a [known bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621) when using `$watchCollection`.

Comment: As much I thought.  Just making sure I wasn't missing something, as that answer had 6 upvotes

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.$watch('searchStr', function (tmpStr){
     if (tmpStr === $scope.searchStr){
       $http.get('http://devclone.wegetmusic.com:9200/weget/_search').success(function(data) {
            $scope.responseData = data; 
          });
        }
    });
```

[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/enjlH8ocN4UBpz67MWrh?p=info) 
In this example we matched new and old string to do search/ send API request for search

Reason to this is to minimize API request while entering data in search field it checks after a time if user didnt typed anything in that time internal then do search thats why we matched new and old value

Comment: I don't understand why you are doing this.  since `newValue` of the watch is always going to equal `$scope.searchStr`, what is the point of checking?  Also it seems `ng-change` and `ng-model-options` tag could handle this just as well as a watch

Answer (score 0):

I found that if $watch is called when the value is changed for the first time, both arguments are set to the new value. This is caused by the following code in angular:

`fn(value, ((last === initWatchVal) ? value : last), current);`

Where `fn` is your handler, `last` is the old value, initialized to a marker function named `initWatchVal`, `value` is the current state of the watched model. Therefore, until we have a "real" old value, the second argument is set to `value`, so the two arguments are the same.